# working of jQuery noConflict

Tags: jquery

i am using jquery no confict. but sum time i am little bit confuse taking about new aliens.

// not working

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($jq) {
    var myTable=$jq(".tblList").dataTable();
    myTable.$jq("input[name=isselected]").change(function () {});
})(jQuery);
```

//works fine

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($jq) {
    var myTable=$jq(".tblList").dataTable();
    //why $jq not works here
    myTable.$("input[name=isselected]").change(function () {});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: because syntactically that is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `myTable.$` *refers to* the jQuery constructor. The `myTable` object doesn't have `$jq` property, it's `undefined` and you can't use an `undefined` value as a function.

In fact, your `$jq` argument has nothing to do with `myTable.$jq`. If you want to get a property using a string you should use the bracket notation: `object[aStringThatContainsNameOfAProperty]`. But since you have the *value* (the jQuery constructor) and not the *key* (`"$"`), by using the bracket notation you will get the same error as the `myObject` object doesn't have:

```
function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
}
```

property (the above string is is the string representation of the jQuery constructor). If the `$jq` variable had `$` string value you could code:

```
myTable[$jq](...)
```